# 2D vector of unknown size

Tags: c++, vector

I defined an empty vector of vectors :

```
vector< vector<int> > v;
```

How do i fill that empty vector with vector of size 2 integers ( from input )  each iteration of while loop?

```
while ( cin >> x >> y ) {
  //....
}
```

Will this one work? Or what's the best and most elegant / effective way of doing it?

```
while ( cin >> x >> y )
{
   vector<int> row;
   row.push_back( x );
   row.push_back( y );
   v.push_back( row );
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, do you want to insert 2 integers into a vector in each iteration?

Comment: `Will this one work` - putting that in your question makes it sound like you haven't tried your own suggestion, which will discourage people from responding.

Comment: what did your compiler say? will it work? Just do it! ...but vectors of vectors is generally not a good idea but you should rethink if you really need the possibility to have rows of different size (Thats what a vector of vectors offers you and if you dont need it you still have to pay for it)

Comment: I wrote it  - compilator didnt say anything but i have never used vectors so i haven't figured out how to print it yet

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you may really want something more like `struct pointer { int x, y; }; std::vector<point> points;`

Comment: `std::cout << v[0][0] << std::endl;` prints the first element

Comment: Unclear. Do you want an `x` by `y` rectangular matrix or a 2 by N matrix containing the values read as `x` and `y`?

Comment: @I want to make 2D vector of 2 integers ( x , y ) which i enter each iteration

Comment: @paxie -  Why not test this with a small program first before asking on SO?  The computer won't explode if you get something wrong.

Comment: Go with the 1D vector of XY structures if possible. vector of vectors has hidden performance costs (each vector is a different block of memory leading to increased cache misses) and in this case you pick up the overhead of a data structure designed to hold a variable number of items with iteration support etc... just to store two integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by JerryCoffin, you probably better use a :

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

and then you might overload the output operator

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o,const Point& xy){
    o << xy.x << " " << xy.y;
    return o;
}
```

and similar the input operator (see e.g. [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm)). And then you can use it like this:

```
int main() {
    Point xy;
    std::vector<Point> v;
    v.push_back(xy);
    std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The another way of doing so is to push the value in a 1-D vector and then push that 1-D vector in 2-D vector. I have also printed the values as a test.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t,n,temp;
    cin>>t;
    vector<vector<int>> value;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        cin>>n;
        vector<int> x;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cin>>temp;
            x.push_back(temp);
        }
        value.push_back(x);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<value[i].size();j++)
        {
            cout<<value[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote it - compilator didnt say anything but i have never used vectors so i haven't figured out how to print it yet

You can print using for example a range based for loop (C++11):

```
for (const auto &vec : v) {     // for every vector in v
    for (const auto &num : vec) // print the numbers
        cout << num << " ";
    cout << '\n';
}
```

And regular for loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j != v[i].size(); ++j) {
        cout << v[i][j] << " ";   
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```